# How to suppress the Java dialog "Unavailable Version of Java Requested"

Tags: java, applet

We have a set of third-party Java applets that were deployed in production and explicitly require Java 1.6* via the  tag properties on the html page.
Now after upgrading client computers to Java 1.7 the following dialog appears:

> Warning - Unavailable Version of Java Requested
>   [Run with latest version] [Cancel]

Is there a way to suppress this dialog?

I looked at different properties available in Java policies but nothing provides the desired effect:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html

Also I monitored where the preference value is stored after clicking "Run with latest version".
The value is only stored in the local Java application cache as a .lap file.
So there is no way to force this setting before the applet is downloaded in the cache.

This seems to be related to Secure Static Versioning.
In the old Java versions there was a key that is not available in 1.6 and later ones.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Deployment\Policy]
"EnableSecureStaticVersioning"=0

So what is the way to disable this feature in latest Java versions?

Comment: Don't you risk implosion if you do this?  You did say that the third-party Java applets explicitly require Java 1.6.  Can you get a new version of the applets from the vendor?

Comment: Things have changed and could have potentially broken between Java 6 and 7 (`TreeSet` certainly comes to mind).  I **strongly discourage** upgrading your client's computers to 1.6 until you can secure Java 7 compatible artifacts from your third parties.  You will save yourself a lot of heartburn if you wait.

Comment: The applets run perfectly with 1.7 and confirmed as compatible by the vendor. Also as per http://java.com/en/download/help/run_old_java.xml Oracle recommends to use the latest version as much as possible. The only thing is this annoying popup. I am looking for some Java policy or deployment property that will allow to suppress this popup.

Comment: '..explicitly require Java 1.6* .. The applets run perfectly with 1.7..'  Those two statements are contradictory.

Comment: No, it is not contradictory. The explicit requirement means that the applet tag on the webpage explicitly specifies the version of Java as java_version=1.6*. This does not prevent the code from running correctly on 1.7 and later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is found in Java 7.40 via Deployment Rule Sets.

Comment: one should read the page https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/introducing_deployment_rule_sets for more information